# what's wrong with my jquery hasClass?

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> 
<title>abc</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery_latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 if( $("#pics_tab1").hasClass("current") )  
   alert("tab1");       
 else
   alert("false");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs">
        <a href="#pics_tab1" class="current"></a>
        <a href="#pics_tab2"></a>
        <a href="#pics_tab3"></a>
        <a href="#pics_tab4"></a>
        <a href="#pics_tab5"></a>
    </div>
```

For some reason i can't find the answer on stack OR google. Maybe i haven't searched enough. But i keep getting: false istead of true no matter what i do. Yet, the class current is asigned to tab1.

Thx in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing your `href` with your `id` -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> 
<title>abc</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery_latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 if( $("#pics_tab_link1").hasClass("current") )  
   alert("tab1");       
 else
   alert("false");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tabs">
    <a id="pics_tab_link1" href="#pics_tab1" class="current"></a>
    <a href="#pics_tab2"></a>
    <a href="#pics_tab3"></a>
    <a href="#pics_tab4"></a>
    <a href="#pics_tab5"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: appreciated thx a lot. I would prefer to leave those hrefs and will just ad id's the same name.. know just let me check..

Answer (score 4):

`$("#pics_tab1")` is an id selector, not a href selector. Change your anchor tags' href attributes to id attributes, and remove the `#`:

```
<a id="pics_tab1" href="yourlinkhere"></a>
```

Comment: o... didn't saw that o my... If it's possible i would not change the hrefs to id's -> there part of an api (i use: touchscroll to mimic iphone scrolling behaviour on webapp).

Comment: If need to keep the hrefs, you can use the attribute equals selector. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You've put the id code inside the href property. You need to use id="pics_tab1"

Comment: this still won't work. you won't want to put the # inside the id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The id property was absent.

try

```
<a id="pics_tab1" href="#pics_tab1" class="current"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to have the `id` attribute of the element set to `pics_tab1`, not the `href`.

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery, ("#pics_tab1") selects "elements with id = pics_tab1.
You have no elements on your page with this id.

```
 <a href="#pics_tab1" class="current"></a>
```

should be

```
  <a id="pics_tab1" href="#pics_tab1" class="current"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('a[href="#pics_tab1"]').hasClass("current");
```